# nested router , model not found error

Tags: ember.js

I'm rather new to ember and figuring out the possible ways to best write my new app.

### This is what I want to create:

**a photoalbum**

- first you see all albums (gallery)
- click on an album shows the
  relevant thumbs
- click on a thumb shows the relevant dia

### This are the restrictions:

I want the gallery, thumbs, and dia, directly navigable by a url

### The navigable url's:

- http://www.bvm.be/
- http://www.bvm.be/#/thumbs/1
- http://www.bvm.be/#/thumbs/1/dia/2

### This is the setup router:

```
bvmEmber.Router.map(function () {
      this.resource('gallery', {path : '/'}, function(){
        this.resource('thumbs', {path : '/thumbs/:gallery_id'}, function(){
            this.resource('dia', {path : '/dia/:dia_id'});
        });
      });
  this.resource('blog', {path : '/blog'});
  this.resource('contact', {path : '/contact'});
});
```

### Common problems:

- dia template won't load with the data demanded in the template
- error occurs : 'Error while loading route: Error: No model was found for 'dia''

### Code example :

http://jsbin.com/kehatiho/1/edit

### My questions:

1. is this a good ember approximation of the app I'm building ?
2. Why do I get the error on the model not find for 'dia'?
3. In the Dia template I want to show the title, name, src of the selected dia. How can I retrieve this?
4. Why can't I do setupController in diarouter?
5. Why does the property needs in diaController not have any affect ?
6. Is my approximation possible with Ember ??

someone any idea, I really like to understand my issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create DS.Model classes for your model objects.  You do that for Gallery, but I don't see `bvmEmber.Dia` anywhere in your code.  Nor do I see `bvmEmber.Thumb`.  So, you'll need to create those model classes.

If you want the URLs you describe, you'll need to do your Router mapping like this:

```
bvmEmber.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('gallery', {path : '/'}, function() {
      this.resource('thumbs', {path : 'thumbs/:gallery_id'}, function(){
          this.resource('dia', {path : 'dia/:dia_id'});
      });
    });
    this.resource('blog', {path : '/blog'});
    this.resource('contact', {path : '/contact'});
});
```

Note that I removed the leading "/" from your `path` properties.  I would suggest fixing these problems with your application and then ask more specific questions about the new problems you have.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Steve, indeed adding the DS.model removed the 'no model for dia found' error, great! But I still encounter an error, now saying 'Error while processing route: dia Cannot read property 'id' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined'. But I don't have any clou where this 'id' stands for. Thanks for helping me out on this! (edits are done in http://jsbin.com/kehatiho/1/edit)

Comment: error 'id' is gone, but I still can't receive the necessary data in the dia template : name, title, description ( is the same as in the thumb template )

Comment: Most likely, you are not serializing the incoming object from the REST resource.  You probably want to implement `extractArray` and `extractSingle` in your `ApplicationSerializer`.  At least implement them and debug the `payload` object.  You can do whatever cleanup you need before calling `this._super()` in the serializer.